# Is there any term for a set generating a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

Let $X$ be a set and $F\subset P(X)$.

Then, the intersection of all sigma-algebra on $X$ containing $F$ is a sigma algebra. And we call this "the sigma algebra generated by $F$.

In topology, we call such set a *subbasis*.

Is there any term for this in measure theory?

Comment: "generating set" would be pretty unambiguous.

Comment: If the sets in $F$ are mutually disjoint, they are called the atoms of the sigma algebra. This is mostly used in finitely generated examples.

Comment: A special type of generating sets are pi-systems.